# Why are two J1939-TP messages with the same source address not transmitting simultaneously?

Tags: can-bus, autosar, j1939

Unable to gateway two J1939-TP messages of same source address from one channel to another at the same time

I was trying to gateway two J1939-TP messages which have the same source address from channel 1 to channel 2. Message 1 is a diagnostic message, and both message have the same priority and periodicity. But when I was reading the data on channel 2, I found that only one message was transmitting at once and if I disable either one of them the other message has no problem transmitting. Please help me find the cause of this issue

Comment: I usually try to route CanTp NPdus with PduR, without CanTp involved. CanIf(Rx) -> PduR -> CanIf(Tx). In case the router also needs it, the PduR has a second reception routing path then to CanTp. Vector usually supports this, but not sure for other stacks (EB, ETAS, .. )

Comment: I have already tried this method, and it is not working.